# Hiding ItemTemplate in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have this code in .aspx page

```
<gridview .....
  <columns>
 ............ 
 ...........
<asp:templatefield Visible="true" headertext="Title" >
<edititemtemplate>
        <asp:checkbox id="chkTitle" runat="server" />
</edititemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>

<asp:commandfield buttontype="Link" edittext="Edit" showeditbutton="true"/>
 </columns>
 </gridview>
```

i only want to show the column when the user clicks on Edit button to edit the row.

Comment: If that does not work, then your code has other problems. You may need to paste more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your GV Data Bound Event Handler (not row data bound):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
     If GridView1.EditIndex = -1 Then
         GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Visible = False
     else
         GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Visible = true
     end if
Next

If GridView1.EditIndex = -1 Then
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Visible = False
End If
```

[Source](http://forums.asp.net/t/1541568.aspx/1)

Comment: How do you know it's the 6th column?

Comment: also i have noticed that its executing the same code n number of times ( i did not count) but makes my page very slow after i place the above code...

Comment: It will be your Nth column from the top, where N is the column that you want to hide. You can loop through your columns and inspect properties, but that's generally a pain. It's just a lot easier if you know which column number it is. So, if you have 5 bound fields, and then one template field below your bound fields in your markup, then you will want to hide the column with index 5 (0-based).

Comment: That should not have slowed down your page significantly. However, I posted a second method for you.

Answer (score 1):

Code such as `GridView.Columns[9].Visible = false;` should work - only thing is that grid data-bind must happen after this line. In case you are relying on the view-state for binding the grid in post-back scenarios then you may try putting `GridView.DataBind()` after you set the column visibility.

Yet another harder way is to set visibility at cell levels in `RowDataBound` event - see [this article](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2008/12/hide-gridview-columns-in-normal-mode.html) that is using this technique.